# meas-square integrable function that is not integrable

Tags: lebesgue-measure

F the Borel sets, and u Lebesgue measure
Show that there exists a mean-square integrable function on X that is not integrable
if X=R

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \frac {sin(x)}{x}$, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|dx = \infty$, so $f(x)$ is not Lebesgue integrable.  However, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2 dx \leq \infty$.